# Optaplanner produces only single chain solution

Tags: optaplanner, chained

I am using Optaplanner to solve an installer booking assignment problem, which is a chaining problem, similar to vehicle routing. An installer(vehicle) may have multiple bookings(customer) assigned to it. I need to implement the chain because I need to evaluate one booking in relation to another booking an a particular order.
So, I declared Booking and Installer as @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty in my Solution. Both Booking and Installer implements Standstill. But only in Booking I declared @PlanningVariable for method getPreviousStandstill().

My config:

```
<solver>
  <!--<environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode>-->

  <!-- Domain model configuration -->
  <solutionClass>InstallationSolution</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>Standstill</entityClass>
  <entityClass>Booking</entityClass>



  <!-- Score configuration -->
  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
    <!--<easyScoreCalculatorClass>org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.score.CloudBalancingEasyScoreCalculator</easyScoreCalculatorClass>-->
    <!--<easyScoreCalculatorClass>org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.score.CloudBalancingMapBasedEasyScoreCalculator</easyScoreCalculatorClass>-->
    <!--<incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.score.CloudBalancingIncrementalScoreCalculator</incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>-->
    <!--<scoreDrl>com/tmrnd/pejal/opta/solver/fulfillmentScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>-->
    <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
    <!--<assertionScoreDirectorFactory>-->
      <!--<easyScoreCalculatorClass>org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.score.CloudBalancingMapBasedEasyScoreCalculator</easyScoreCalculatorClass>-->
    <!--</assertionScoreDirectorFactory>-->
  </scoreDirectorFactory>

  <!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
  <termination>
    <!-- <secondsSpentLimit>20</secondsSpentLimit>-->
    <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>15</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>
  <constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>

  </constructionHeuristic>
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector/>
      <swapMoveSelector/>
      <subChainChangeMoveSelector>
        <selectReversingMoveToo>true</selectReversingMoveToo>
      </subChainChangeMoveSelector>
      <subChainSwapMoveSelector>
        <selectReversingMoveToo>true</selectReversingMoveToo>
      </subChainSwapMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
    <acceptor>
      <entityTabuSize>20</entityTabuSize>

    </acceptor>
    <forager>
      <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
  </localSearch>
</solver>
```

When I try to solve(), I got one installer with all bookings asssigned to him. What do I need to do to improve the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial guess would be you have only 1 anchor (1 installer) known to OptaPlanner. Check if the Solution's List's size is bigger than 1 in size. Then check if getter has `@ValueRangeProvider` and if the id of that ValueRangeProvider is added in the `@PlanningEntity`'s valueRangeProviderRefs.

Also be aware of a common pitfall that might apply here too (but shouldn't if you use value range providers properly): `list.add(list)` instead of `list.addAll(list)`.

Comment: I changed the facts.addAll() to facts.add() in getProblemFacts(), but still having the same problem. I am also encountering the following exception after I uncomment/changed my `@PlanningVariable` to be CHAINED:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local Search phase started with an uninitialized Solution. First initialize the Solution. For example, run a Construction Heuristic phase first.

But, before the exception, the program logged that :
Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (1456), time spent (15875), best score (-2761hard/-195507soft).

Comment: I think it's time to go back to reading the docs instead of making random changes :) Especially read the chapter Planning configuration about chained variables etc.

Comment: Thank you. I think i must've read the previous version's documentation, and got confused. By the way, I am currently using version 6.1.0 Final. You are right, I changed back to facts.addAll(). While testing yesterday, I adjusted the scores (Hard/Soft) in the scoreDrl, and got it going. I will be fine-tuning my scoreDrl from now on.